# Save Data when ViewPager page changes

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm trying to save data a user enters in a fragment to a file.

Scenario: 
one viewpager and 7 fragments

A user starts in fragment 0 and can enter text into edittexts,
by swiping, using tabhost or pressing floating arrows the user can switch to other fragments.

I want to save alle entered text of the fragment the user leaves with the methods above.

I tried a *`OnPageChangeListener`*, but there i can't get the previous tab. I logged the values of the implementation methods *`onPageScrolled, onPageSelected, onPageScrollStateChanged`*.

Non of these seem to work for my needs.

`onPageScrolled`  is called several times and shows only the current tab until it is of screen, the offset is different and not always starts by **0.0**, so i can't use this reliably.

`onPageSelected` is the only reliable one but only returns the new current tab

`onPageScrollStateChanged` has no information i could use to determine the tab

I also looked into `onInterceptTouchEvent` in the `ViewPager` but this is also some times invoked several times (for MOVE events) and does not always work for every tab.

Is there a way to get this cost efficent? I want to store the data in an encrypted file and don't want to do this several times over.

Comment: use viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(6);

Comment: please read the whole question I want to store the information in an encrypted file when the current fragment changes so i don't need to change that.

Comment: have you tried to do it in `fragment.onPause()` that is called before it becomes invisible?

Comment: `onSavedInstanceState` will do the trick.

Comment: @Wizard tryed that right now but `onPause()` is not called while switching from the current tab to a neigbhour. If i'am on tab 0 and switch to 1 nothing happends if I switch to 2 `onPause()` is called. Even if i set `OffscreenPageLimit(0)`. But that was a nice suggestion I didn't even think about something so obvious ;)

Comment: okay.. there is one more `setUserVisibleHint`. But you have to manage several conditions over there.. as it may be called even before `onCreateView`

Comment: try using setUserVisibleHint..

Comment: Okay thanks i'll try that later have to move around a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the suggestions didn't work for my case I came up with another idea I wan't to share with others.

First instead of focusing on the ViewPager to suite my needs I thought wouldn't it be clever to led the fragment know if its changed and handle that instead.

So I created an abstract class extending the android Fragment with a boolean attribute `dataChanged` which I check every time the `OnPageChangeListener` calls `onPageSelected` (iterate over all fragments in the pager).

Naturally all Fragments in the pager should extend the abstract class. Furthermore I added abstract methods `save()` and `load()` to the abstract class.

So in `onPageSelected(int position)`, after saving all changes for all fragments, which should only be one at a time, I load the data of the now selected fragment via the `position` attribute.

There was but one problem. If a fragment was paused and resumed the dataChanged attribute was always true if I set it in onTextChangeListeners, because of the automatic loading of widget values that android does. So I also `override` `onResume` to set the `dataChanged` to `false`.

**Also every MyFragment has to handle the dataChanged attribute in the `save()` and `load()` method.**

**Abstract Fragment**

```
public abstract class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private boolean dataChanged = false;

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setDataChanged(false);
    }

    public boolean isDataChanged() {
        return dataChanged;
    }

    public void setDataChanged(boolean dataChanged) {
        this.dataChanged = dataChanged;
    }

    public abstract void save();

    public abstract void load();
}
```

**OnPageChangeListener of ViewPager**

```
fragmentViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            ...
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                for(Fragment f : fragments) {
                    if(f instanceof MyFragment && ((MyFragment)f).isDataChanged()) {
                        ((MyFragment) f).save();
                    }
                }

                if(fragmentViewPager.getCurrentItem() == position) {
                    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.view_pager + ":" + fragmentViewPager.getCurrentItem());
                    if(fragment instanceof MyFragment) {
                        ((MyFragment) fragment).load();
                    }
                }
            }
            ...
});
```